# Making os independent file-paths

Tags: python, r, operating-system, filepath

So in python there is a really useful library called `os.path` which allows users to have OS agnostic file paths. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

So scripts can be written to run in windows, mac, and linux quite easily.

Is there a comparable library for `R`?

Comment: https://here.r-lib.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base function: [`file.path`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/file.path)

There is also another [set of functions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/files) for file manipulation.